# Drive EV tool with Drupal-7 using webforms and charts

Tags: drupal-7, calculator

I have to create a calculator like https://sonomacleanpower.org/drive-ev-choose-ev.

I have to develop a calculator using Drupal-7 with Webfroms calculator and Drupal modules such as charts.

Is it possible to create a calculator like this using Drupal-7 modules?

Comment: Yes it need some custom development, but everything is possible . You need to start with Drupal 7 module creation , https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this using hook_form().

Comment: Do I have to do a php code or can I implement this using modules?

Comment: Not at the moment.